# Importing Data from csv fills my notebook with large list

Tags: import

Sorry for bother you with such a trivial problem, but I can't stand it!

I use `Import[file]` to read a CSV and I get my notebook fill up with hundred of lines of numbers.

I tried `Quiet[Import[file]]` but was useless.

Comment: Try something like `data = Import[ file];` - it is the semicolon at the end that prevents the result from being printed in the notebook.